# How to modify text with sed or awk

Tags: unix, sed, awk

I would like to convert this file

```
hg19_ct_UserTrack_3545_12805 range=chr1:117217481-117217677 5'pad=0 3'pad=0 strand=+ repeatMasking=none
TCCTCATGAGTTTACATTCTTTATTAGTTTCTCTGTTTATGGTCATCTTC
CCCTGGGTATGTAAGCTGTCTGTGGGCTGGAATCTGGTCTGTCTTGTTCT
CTGGTGTTGGTCCAATGCCTAGAATAATGCCTAGCACATAGGATGTGATC
AACAAATATTTGTTGAATGAATACGTTCTAGTTGGAAAGACAATAAA .... etc
```

To

```
range=chr1:117217481-117217677 5'pad=0 3'pad=0 strand=+ repeatMasking=none
TCCTCATGAGTTTACATTCTTTATTAGTTTCTCTGTTTATGGTCATCTTC
CCCTGGGTATGTAAGCTGTCTGTGGGCTGGAATCTGGTCTGTCTTGTTCT
CTGGTGTTGGTCCAATGCCTAGAATAATGCCTAGCACATAGGATGTGATC
AACAAATATTTGTTGAATGAATACGTTCTAGTTGGAAAGACAATAAA .... etc
```

I have been trying awk and sed without luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As this is a simple substitution I would use `sed`:

```
$ sed '1s/\w\+ //' file
range=chr1:117217481-117217677 5'pad=0 3'pad=0 strand=+ repeatMasking=none
TCCTCATGAGTTTACATTCTTTATTAGTTTCTCTGTTTATGGTCATCTTC
CCCTGGGTATGTAAGCTGTCTGTGGGCTGGAATCTGGTCTGTCTTGTTCT
CTGGTGTTGGTCCAATGCCTAGAATAATGCCTAGCACATAGGATGTGATC
AACAAATATTTGTTGAATGAATACGTTCTAGTTGGAAAGACAATAAA
```

Explanation:

```
1   # First line only
s/  # Subsitution 
\w+ # Match one or more word character follow by a space
/   # Replace with
/   # Nothing
```

By default `sed` prints to `stdout` but you can save the changes to file directly by using the `-i` option: `sed -i '1s/\w\+ //' file`.

Comment: GNU `sed` — not POSIX `sed`, for example.

Comment: @user1879573 the way to say thank you on stackoverflow is by upvoting all helpful answers and accepting the most helpful answer by accepting it. You accept an answer by clicking the tick mark next to it. For more infomation read the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq).

Answer (score 0):

you need just remove `hg19_ct_UserTrack_3545_12805` from the first line?

then try:

```
awk 'NR==1{sub(/^[^ ]* /,"")}1' file
```